# what compiler optimizations would be needed to optimize out this recursive call?

Tags: c++, rust, llvm, compiler-optimization

Here are two versions of a trivial arithmetic expression evaluator (playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2021&gist=d3da06b0077b29e0e3ac85720c567dd8)
The second version uses a recursive call to reuse some code (obviously not worth the effort in this toy example, but that's why it's a toy example).
I'm convinced that a sufficiently smart compiler could realize that the recursive call to `eval_slow(Sum(...))` does not itself make any recursive calls, and therefore is safe to inline, and `eval_slow` should actually compile to the same assembly as `eval_fast`. In practice, rustc currently does not perform this optimization, and `eval_slow` contains a recursive call (see assembly output in playground link).

Are there optimizing compilers that are capable of performing this type of optimization (for any language)? Is there a name for this type of optimization in the compiler literature? Is this likely to be optimized correctly in the near future, or is (the general version of) this a very hard open problem?

```
pub enum Expr {
    Lit(isize),
    Sum(isize, isize),
    Sub(isize, isize),
}

// simple and fast
pub fn eval_fast(expr: Expr) -> isize {
    use Expr::*;
    match expr {
        Lit(x) => x,
        Sum(x, y) => x + y,
        Sub(x, y) => x - y
    }
}

// we'd like to inline the recursive call to `eval_slow(Sum(...))`, but it doesn't happen. 
pub fn eval_slow(expr: Expr) -> isize {
    use Expr::*;
    match expr {
        Lit(x) => x,
        Sum(x, y) => x + y,
        Sub(x, y) => eval_slow(Sum(x, -y))
    }
}
```

NOTE: also tagging this as C++ since my questions aren't rust-specific, though my example is (and afaik it's quite possible that this optimization would live in the language-agnostic passes of LLVM anyway)

EDIT:
TCO is *not* what I'm looking for - the logic above does not rely on the recursive call being in tail position. Also, contrary to some initial comments, Clang does not solve this for C++ in the general case - here's an example which has been modified such that the recursive call is not in tail position, and in which the recursive call is not inlined. https://godbolt.org/z/cGabvvvro (yes, one version prints twice - shouldn't affect main point)

Comment: I only know that for the visual studio c++ compiler, you might want to take a look at the  [`__force_inline` keyword](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=msvc-170)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/43K8hxf98

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Interesting that in [this case](https://godbolt.org/z/TfsqKbz76) it does not inline the call. So much about zero cost abstractions :-P

Comment: @chrysante Use -O2.

Comment: Interestingly, the same code (conceptually) that [in C++ is optimized by clang](https://godbolt.org/z/5Y1GsvPx1), is [not optimized in Rust by rustc](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/bn6TsWT74). It's known that rustc generates degenerate LLVM IR. Anyway, I removed the C++ tag since it optimizes well in C++.

Comment: However, beware that while this optimizes in C++ in this simple made-up example, it is very likely it won't be optimized in real cases, where the function is large.

Comment: If you mark the function as `#[inline(always)]` though, [it does inline](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/4sPEWoqjP), so I guess this answers the question?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman using `#[inline(always)]` doesn't work here. It merely posponds code generation for that function (all `inline` functions are generated at call-site) so you don't see code in godbolt but it would generate recursion at callsite. See this: https://godbolt.org/z/cveh447T7

Comment: I managed to catch 2 miscompilations using this code! https://godbolt.org/z/c7ffrjYY9

Comment: Opened an issue for Rust compiler: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/114312

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I readded the C++ tag, along with a slightly more complex C++ example which does not optimize well - see edit at the end of main post

Comment: @ajp you're missing `break;`. https://godbolt.org/z/fTPx4oPWr

Comment: @ecatmur oops - see here for updated version that contains recursive call https://godbolt.org/z/cGabvvvro (i know behavior is now not identical because eval_slow prints twice - but should still be inlineable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GCC calls this "recursive inlining":

> - `max-inline-insns-recursive`
> - `max-inline-insns-recursive-auto`
>
>   - Specifies the maximum number of instructions an out-of-line copy of a self-recursive inline function can grow into by performing recursive inlining.
>   - `--param max-inline-insns-recursive` applies to functions declared `inline`. For functions not declared `inline`, recursive inlining happens only when `-finline-functions` (included in `-O3`) is enabled; `--param max-inline-insns-recursive-auto` applies instead.
> - `max-inline-recursive-depth`
> - `max-inline-recursive-depth-auto`
>
>   - Specifies the maximum recursion depth used for recursive inlining.
>
>   `--param max-inline-recursive-depth` applies to functions declared `inline`. For functions not declared `inline`, recursive inlining happens only when `-finline-functions` (included in `-O3`) is enabled; `--param max-inline-recursive-depth-auto` applies instead.
>
> (etcetera)

According to [this presentation from 2015](https://llvm.org/devmtg/2015-04/slides/recursion-inlining-2015.pdf), LLVM does not consider self-recursive (other than tail recursive) functions for inlining. I haven't looked at the code to see how straightforward it would be to add; it would necessarily require some level of heuristic.

An amusing technique to force LLVM to inline the non-tail recursive call is to [generate multiple copies](https://godbolt.org/z/h671Gb5qT) of the function using the (C++) template machinery, then rely on the optimizer to inline them back in and discard the redundant copies:

```cpp
template<int I = 0>
int eval_slow(expr e)
{
    int ret;
    switch (e.op)
    {
        case expr::lit: ret = e.i1; break;
        case expr::plus: ret = e.i1 + e.i2; break;
        case expr::minus: ret = eval_slow<(I + 1) % 2>(expr{expr::plus, e.i1, -e.i2}); break;
    }
    std::cout << ret;
    return ret;
}
int eval_slow(expr e) { return eval_slow<>(e); }
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, unlike [Clang](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:14,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:14,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:14,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:14),source:%27%23include+%3Ccstdint%3E%0A%23include+%3Cutility%3E%0A%0Aenum+ExprType+%7B%0A++++Lit,+Add,+Sub%0A%7D%3B%0A%0Astruct+Expr%7B%0A++++ExprType+type%3B%0A++++int64_t+f%3B%0A++++int64_t+s%3B%0A%7D%3B%0A%0A%0Aint64_t+eval(Expr+e)+%7B%0A++++switch+(e.type)+%7B%0A++++++++case+Lit:+return+e.f%3B%0A++++++++case+Add:+return+e.f+%2B+e.s%3B%0A++++++++case+Sub:+return+eval(%7BAdd,+e.f,+-e.s%7D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang1600,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:21.15203021718602,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:llvmOptPipelineView,i:(%27-fno-discard-value-names%27:%270%27,compilerName:%27x86-64+clang+16.0.0%27,demangle-symbols:%270%27,dump-full-module:%271%27,editorid:1,filter-debug-info:%270%27,filter-inconsequential-passes:%271%27,filter-instruction-metadata:%270%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,selectedFunction:%27eval(Expr)%27,selectedIndex:43,sidebarWidth:250,treeid:0),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27LLVM+Opt+Pipeline+Viewer+x86-64+clang+16.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:45.51463644948063,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4), Rust doesn't perform tail call elimination successfully in that case by default.

However, if we switch from recursion to loop, we could get conceptually same code without recursion:

```rust
pub fn eval_slow(mut expr: Expr) -> isize {
    use Expr::*;
    loop{
        expr = match expr {
            Lit(x) => return x,
            Sum(x, y) => return x + y,
            Sub(x, y) => Sum(x, -y),
        };
    }
}
```

Result:

```
example::eval_slow:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi]
        test    rax, rax
        je      .LBB0_3
        cmp     rax, 2
        jne     .LBB0_2
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        xor     eax, eax
        sub     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rdi], 1
        mov     qword ptr [rdi + 16], rax
        add     rax, rcx
        ret
.LBB0_3:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        ret
.LBB0_2:
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rdi + 16]
        add     rax, rcx
        ret
```

[godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:16,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:7,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:16,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:7),source:%27pub+enum+Expr+%7B%0A++++Lit(isize),%0A++++Sum(isize,+isize),%0A++++Sub(isize,+isize),%0A%7D%0A%0Apub+fn+eval_slow(mut+expr:+Expr)+-%3E+isize+%7B%0A++++use+Expr::*%3B%0A++++loop%7B%0A++++++++expr+%3D+match+expr+%7B%0A++++++++++++Lit(x)+%3D%3E+return+x,%0A++++++++++++Sum(x,+y)+%3D%3E+return+x+%2B+y,%0A++++++++++++Sub(x,+y)+%3D%3E+Sum(x,+-y),%0A++++++++%7D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Rust+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:55.23615038223899,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:r1710,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,debugCalls:%271%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:rust,libs:!(),options:%27-Copt-level%3D3%27,overrides:!(),selection:(endColumn:12,endLineNumber:21,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:12,selectionStartLineNumber:21,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+rustc+1.71.0+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:44.76384961776102,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Comment: thanks! partially useful, but I'm not satisfied, because "tail call" should not be required here - see Edit to main post